# Using XSD in PySpark

Tags: azure, pyspark, xsd, azure-synapse

I am building a datawarehouse in Azure Synapse where one of the sources are about 20 different types of XML files (with a different XSD scheme) and 1 base scheme.

What I am looking for is to get all XML elements and store them in files (1 per type) in my data lake. For that I need to have unique names per element, for example the whole path as a name. I tried to define dicts per type with all element names, but this is quite some work. To automate this (XSDs are updated yearly), I tried to code this out in Excel and VBA, but the XSDs are quite complex with nested complex types etc.
Below is a snippet of the baseschema.xsd:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.website.org/typ/1/baseschema/schema" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:iwmo="http://www.website.org/typ/1/baseschema/schema">
    <xs:complexType name="Complex_Address">
        ...
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Home" type="iwmo:Complex_House" minOccurs="0">
                ...
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Postalcode" type="iwmo:Simple_Postalcode" minOccurs="0">
                ...
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Streetname" type="iwmo:Simple_Streetname" minOccurs="0">
                ...
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Areaname" type="iwmo:Simple_Areaname" minOccurs="0">
                ...
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="CountryCode" type="iwmo:Simple_CountryCode" minOccurs="0">
                ...
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Complex_House">
        ...
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Housenumber" type="iwmo:Simple_Housenumber">
                ...
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Houseletter" type="iwmo:Simple_Houseletter" minOccurs="0">
                ...
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="HousenumberAddition" type="iwmo:Simple_HousenumberAddition" minOccurs="0">
                ...
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="IndicationAddress" type="iwmo:Simple_IndicationAddress" minOccurs="0">
                ...
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="Complex_MessageIdentification">
            ...
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Identification" type="iwmo:Simple_IdentificationMessage">
                ...
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Date" type="iwmo:Simple_Date">
                ...
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Complex_Product">
            ...
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Categorie" type="iwmo:Simple_ProductCategory">
                ...
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Code" type="iwmo:Simple_ProductCode" minOccurs="0">
                ...
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Complex_XsdVersion">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="BaseschemaXsdVersion" type="iwmo:Simple_Version">
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="MessageXsdVersion" type="iwmo:Simple_Version">
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

And here a snippet of the xsd of 1 of the message types:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:typ="http://www.website.org/typ/1/baseschema/schema" xmlns:type1="http://www.website.org/typ/1/type1/schema" targetNamespace="http://www.website.org/typ/1/type1/schema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.website.org/typ/1/baseschema/schema" schemaLocation="baseschema.xsd"></xs:import>
    <xs:element name="Message" type="type1:Root"></xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="Root">
        ...
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Header" type="type1:Header"></xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Client" type="type1:Client"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Header">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Person" type="typ:Simple_SpecialCode">
                ...
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="MessageIdentification" type="typ:Complex_MessageIdentification">
                ...
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="XsdVersion" type="typ:Complex_XsdVersion">
                ...
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Client">
                ...
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="AssignedProducts" type="type1:AssignedProducts"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="AssignedProducts">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="AssignedProduct" type="type1:AssignedProduct"  maxOccurs="unbounded"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="AssignedProduct">
        ...
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ToewijzingNummer" type="typ:Simple_Nummer">
                ...
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Product" type="typ:Complex_Product" minOccurs="0">
                ...
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Then this would be the desired output:

```
Header_Person
Header_MessageIdentification_Identification
Header_MessageIdentification_Date
Header_XsdVersion_BaseschemaXsdVersion
Header_XsdVersion_MessageXsdVersion
Client_AssignedProduct_ToewijzingNummer
Client_AssignedProduct_Product_Category
Client_AssignedProduct_Product_Code
```

In the baseschema I also added a nested complex type, to show the complexity.

Is there some kind of package or something in Python that can help me achieve this? Also a tool that can just create this list of elements in a text file would be great, I then can easily copy that into a variable.

I'm not sure if I'm clear about my requirements, if this is posted in the correct group with the correct tags, but I hope someone can point me into a good solution.

Ronald

Comment: I found a workaround after all where I put all fields from the xsds in variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround after all where I put all fields from the xsds in variables. It's not ideal, but any other way would be too complex.